# Getting error while creating Cloud Functions through UI using Inline Editor

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-functions, apache-beam

I've been using Cloud Functions for quite some time now but recently it is giving me an error while creating it through the UI using Inline Editor. The error that I get is:

```
Error
The request contains invalid arguments "event_trigger": "projects/my-project-id/buckets/my-bucket-id expected to match template projects/_/buckets/{bucket}"

Tracking Number: **************(some tracking number)
```

Basically I'm trying to create a function that must get triggered when a file is created/uploaded in a specific GCS bucket that ultimately kicks-off a dataflow job. The function gets deployed when uploaded from local through Cloud SDK Command Line but does not get triggered.
I've created several functions the same way(UI/Command Line) before. Don't know why it is not working now.

The code that I'm using is:

```
const google = require('googleapis');

exports.jobName = function(event, callback) {
 const file = event.data;
 if (file.resourceState === 'exists' && file.name) {
     console.log(file.name);
   console.log(event.data);
   google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }

     if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
       authClient = authClient.createScoped([
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
       ]);
     }

     const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: 'v1b3', auth: authClient });

     dataflow.projects.templates.create({
       projectId: 'project-id',
       resource: {
         parameters: {
           inputFile: `gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}`,
           filename:`${file.name}`
         },
         jobName: 'cloud-fn',
         gcsPath: 'gs://some-bucket/Job'
       }
     }, function(err, response) {
       if (err) {
         console.error("problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
       }
       console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
       callback();
     });

   });
 }
};
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "googleapis": "^18.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Same here, it seems there is a problem in the frontend, since a workaround is to do any update from API directly.

Comment: @san983 what update? I'm sorry I didn't quite follow you on that...

Comment: Please follow this thread https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65800904